# How should I get UN-rotated JPEG image file from ghostscript?

Tags: image, pdf, jpeg, ghostscript, image-rotation

I am running with crazy issue in `ghostscript 9.15`.I have two commands for converting PDF to JPEG images,which has difference in height and width only.

Command 1st

> -q -dUseCropBox -dBATCH -dDOINTERPOLATE -dMaxBitmap=300000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dPDFFitPage -dPrinted=false -r144 -g200x200 -sDEVICE=jpeg  -dJPEGQ=100  -sOutputFile="output.jpg" "input.pdf" -c quit

Command 2nd

> -q -dUseCropBox -dBATCH -dDOINTERPOLATE -dMaxBitmap=300000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dPDFFitPage -dPrinted=false -r144 -g200x199 -sDEVICE=jpeg  -dJPEGQ=100  -sOutputFile="output.jpg" "input.pdf" -c quit

As you can see, **command has difference in -g parameter only**.

In first command I have used `-g200x200` and in second command `-g200x199`.

First command gives rotated JPEG while second command gives UN-rotated JPEG file.Is there any utility inside ghostscript which differentiate my command from height and width perspective.

How should I get UN-rotated JPEG image file by using same height and width`(-g200x200)` while converting PDF to JPEG image file ?

Answer (score 0):

The main answer is 'don't use PDFFitPage'. That feature automatically rotates the output to fit 'best' on the declared media. If that isn't an option then you will have to do some PostScript programming.

You can fnd the code which does the resizing (and rotation) in ghostpdl/gs/Resource/Init/pdf_main.ps, the function /pdf_PDF2PS_matrix

Comment: I don't have auto rotation problem always.There are some PDF files say high resolution image containing PDF, PDF with different size of pages including different size of images.So I am finding better solution which will work for all PDF without any need of postscript to rotate image again.Thanks